# Handler method not firing when called by form in Razor Pages

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, methods, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I've gone through dozens of articles, docs, and stack overflow questions (even the one with a similar intro)regarding the same issues but it still persists.
I've tried this with putting the functions in the .cshtml.cs page and on the .cshtml page, named and unnamed handler names, different framework for sending emails, and adding an empty action field in the form along with other fixes but the issue seems to be that the handler method itself is not firing while the form is submitting. Any and all help is appreciated and please let me know if more information is needed.

My HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" asp-page-handler="email">
                <!-- Name input-->
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control" name="clientName" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." required/>
                    <label for="name">Full name*</label>
                </div>
                <!-- Email address input-->
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control" name="clientEmail" type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" required/>
                    <label for="email">Email address*</label>
                </div>
                <!-- Phone number input-->
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control" name="clientPhone" type="tel" placeholder="(123) 456-7890"/>
                    <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
                </div>
                <!-- Message input-->
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="clientMessage" type="text" placeholder="Enter your message here..." style="height: 10rem" required></textarea>
                    <label for="message">Message*</label>
                </div>
                <!-- Submit Button-->
                <div class="d-grid"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button></div>
            </form>
```

My functions as they are currently:

```
public void OnPostEmail()
        {
            var clientEmail = Request.Form["clientEmail"];
            var clientName = Request.Form["clientName"];
            var clientPhone = Request.Form["clientPhone"];
            var clientMessage = Request.Form["clientMessage"];

            sendEmail(clientEmail, clientName, clientPhone, clientMessage);
        }

        public void sendEmail(string clientEmail, string clientName, string clientPhone, string clientMessage)
        {
            var errorMessage = "";
            try
            {
                // Initialize WebMail helper
                WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.google.com";
                WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
                WebMail.UserName = "***@gmail.com";
                WebMail.Password = "MYPASSWORD";
                WebMail.From = "***@gmail.com";
                WebMail.EnableSsl = true;

                // Send email
                WebMail.Send(to: clientEmail,
                    subject: $"Request from:  + {clientName}",
                    body: $"{clientMessage}\nPhone: {clientPhone}\nEmail: {clientEmail}"
                );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @PotatoJesus, From the code you provided, I don't find any error in it, Is this project using `Asp.Net Core Web App` template? After you submit the form, is there any error message or just nothing happens?

Comment: Hello! @XinranShen Yes it's Asp.Net Core Web App and nothing happens, no errors.

Comment: Are there other methods on the current page? Did you change anything in the settings?

Comment: @XinranShen So I remade the application to more closely resemble the WebMail tutorial by Microsoft to see what happens and the functions are calling but now I'm getting the error message:  **Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.** is there a reference or Nuget package I must add?

Comment: you can check if System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null or not, it's available only in web pages or web services.

Comment: @XinranShen how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2eb9d810-c637-4a73-a4eb-60521915bee6/could-not-load-type-systemwebhttpcontext-for-ffmpegconverter?forum=aspdotnetcore).